# Unable to catch the Dropdown selected value in a textbox inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` inside a repeater and whenever the selected text is changed, I have to show it in a `TextBox` but I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error

```
protected void Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl   = (DropDownList)  sender;
    RepeaterItem item  = (RepeaterItem)  ddl .NamingContainer;
    TextBox txt        = (TextBox) item.FindControl("TextBox4");
    txt.Text           = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: Which line fails? Is TextBox inside a repeater too?

Comment: The last line txt.Text = ddl.SelectedItem.Text; yes textbox is inside the repeater

Comment: @Newbie Did you make sure that `txt` is defined?

Comment: What you mean by txt is defined??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable Ddl dropdowns autopost back property to true and just add following line of code:

```
protected virtual void RepeaterItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList MyList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddl");
    MyList.SelectedIndexChanged += ddl_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

protected void Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RepeaterItem item  = (RepeaterItem)  Page.FindControl("repeatorid");
     TextBox txt        = (TextBox) item.FindControl("TextBox4");
     txt.Text           = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;     
 }
```

Comment: ok,check out following link
http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/aspdropdownlist-does-not-fire-onselectedindexchanged-event-in-an-asprepeater/

Comment: My textbox is in footer template.